publishing to pub.dev: which files to check into GitHub? explicitly export files?
I have a single source code file for my Widget which contains all the public and private classes. I also have a file with USADateFormatter, which the example/lib/main.dart users (I'm fine sharing this as well)
Googling returns lots of basic tutorials but nothing detailed
First, what files should I check into GitHub, especially for the example app? Sharing all the generated files seems silly, as anyone cloning will regenerate them anyway. Would flutter clean be appropriate?
Second, various tutorials differ on explicitly exporting files from this package. Any rules of thumb?
Cheers
